# Order of elements in groups: is my answer/reasoning correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

### Question:

Let $(G, o)$ be a group with identity $e$. Let $a\in G$ and suppose the order of $a=l$. Suppose $a^j=e$, where $j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show $l | j$

That is, show $\exists c \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $j=cl$

### Attempted solution:

Given $a^j=e$, we know $\left<a\right>=\left\{a^1, a^2, . . . , a^j=e\right\}$. That is, $\left<a\right>$ has $j$ elements. But the order of $a=l$, by the supposition. Therefore, it must be that $l=j$. So we have that if $c=1$, $j=cl$ (because it can obviously divide itself), which is what I wanted to show.

I have an elementary understanding of algebra, so I am unsure if my answer is ignoring important facts from the question.

Comment: If $j=nl$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $a^{j}=a^{nl}=(a^l)^n=e^n=e$, so $l=j$ doesn't necessarily hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have $l = j$. Clearly we must have $j \ge l$. Let $a^j = e$. By the division algorithm, $j = kl + r$ for some integers $k$ and $0 \leq r < l$. Then $a^{kl+r}= e = (a^l)^ka^r = a^r$. You can now argue that $r$ is actually zero, so that $kl = j$, that is, $l$ divides $j$.

Comment: So I can argue that $r=0$ because if $r$ were any other integer, it would imply $r$ is the smallest integer s.t. $a^r=e$, contradicting $ord(a)=l$.

However, I am still wondering if I truly understand how order works. Was I correct to assume there were $j$ elements in $\left<a\right>$, which is the same as its order?

Comment: Yes, beause $ 0 \leq r < l$. You can show that for a finite cyclic group $G = <g> of order n, $ that ord($g^m$) = $n\over(m,n)$.